# Pandas/Python Filtering a DF for column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, quantile

I was looking for a way to filter a df for value in a column in a `groupby` and also in another instance when calling that df column.

For example:

So to plot this dfs column_betas as below, but only when a different column (called column_value) has value like 2?

```
df['column_betas'] # ( when a different column called `column_value` is 2)
```

and for below when I am running a group by for the city column, but only when the `column_value` column = 2?

```
df.groupby(['City']).quantile(.5)
```

I am trying to avoid creating additional dfs that filter for a certain value for `column_value` and instead try to call that value when just calling that df for that specific column value or in the `groupby`.

Comment: what is your desired output

Comment: Output should be the grouped by quantiles but only when the df column_value is filtered for a specific value 

and the df values for df['column_betas] column of df but when another column in that df is filtered for a specific value

Comment: Did you try `df=df[df['column_betas']==2]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command gets `df['column_betas"]`, where the value column is 2:

```
df[df["value"]==2]["column_betas"]
```

and this command does group by only on rows that has value of 2 in value column

```
df[df["value"]==2].groupby(["City"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `df` with

```
df[df['column_value']==2]
```

So `df['column_betas']` becomes `df[df['column_value']==2]['column_betas']`

and `df.groupby(['City']).quantile(.5)` becomes `df[df['column_value']==2].groupby(['City']).quantile(.5)`